# YouTube Analytics

Tags: python, django, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get earnings details for user from YouTube

I followed below url to get earnings

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#Content_Owner_Reports

i passed request like below

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D*******************&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=earnings&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

but the result is

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "unauthorized",
    "message": "Insufficient permission to access this report."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Insufficient permission to access this report."
 }
}
```

My questions are:

1. My request is right?
2. How to get earnings in YouTube API?
3. `contentOwner==OWNER_NAME` How to get OWNER_NAME for YouTube CMS?
4. What is YouTube CMS?
   Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the link you posted:  [Sample API Requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#Content_Owner_Reports)

> You also have to be authenticated as the specified channel or content
>   owner so that the APIs Explorer can authorize your API requests using
>   OAuth 2.0.

Answer to your first question is: No your request isn't correct. You need to be authenticated before you can access the data. [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication)

Also: YouTube Content Manager ([CMS](https://cms.youtube.com/))